# Orientation problem when coding on Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, orientation

I write a page and I add

```
this.SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait | SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape;
```

in the constructor.

After letting a messagebox popup and change orientation from portrait to landscape, I found that the UI under the messagebox didn’t change orientation from portrait to landscape as expected.

Is there anything I lose in code or this is the limitation of the UI framework now?

Answer (score 2):

The MessageBox is modal and blocks the UI thread so such events like orientation changed won't be processed however the underlying UI should adapt to the orientation change once the message box is dismissed.

Comment: Tried this out, and it does appear to behave this way.